# same component with different background-color

Tags: css, vue.js, components

I've created a component and use it multiple times on one of my vue pages.
Now I wanna change the background-color for each use of this component.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="project-card" :style="{backgroundColor: color}">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ description }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProjectCard',
  props: {
    title: String,
    description: String
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      color: "#000"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is my vue page, where I use the component:

```
<template>
  <div class="projects">
    <ProjectCard 
      title="Projekt 01"
      description="Lorem Ipsum"
    />
    <ProjectCard
      title="Projekt 02"
      description="Lorem Ipsum"
    />
</template>

<script>
import ProjectCard from '@/components/ProjectCard.vue'

export default {
  name: 'projects',
  components: {
    ProjectCard
  }
}
</script>
```

Is it now possible to change the color data of the project-card component on my projects page, like I changed the text props?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass color also as a prop:

```
 <ProjectCard
      title="Projekt 02"
      description="Lorem Ipsum"
      color= "#000F"
    />
<ProjectCard
      title="Projekt 02"
      description="Lorem Ipsum"
      color= "#00FF00"
    />
```

and in script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProjectCard',
  props: {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    color:String
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      color: "#000"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: oh that's so obvious! Thanks for your help :)